# How to compare the date of a timestamp with a date?

Tags: php, sql

I want to compare just the date of a timestamp in my MYSQL server with the curdate() function. How can i take just the data from the timestamp field in my DB? ( It contains date + time) Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for db you can use the date function

```
DATE(NOW()) = DATE(your_date)


select * from my_table 
where  DATE(curdate()) = DATE(your_date);
```

Comment: Isn't a way to get that with a SQL query? I just have to compare the date of my log_time field with the curdate()

Comment: I have update the answer hope is wgat you are looking for

Answer (score 0):

You can try with MYSQL [DATE_FORMAT()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format) function:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT('2016-19-06 17:40:01', '%Y-%m-%d');
```

Or in PHP [date()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) :

```
date('Y-m-d',strtotime('2016-19-06 17:40:01'));
```

In that way **this** should work:

SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE DATE(`log_time`) = CURDATE();

Comment: I'' prefer the query option, but i would like something like SELECT ... FROM login WHERE log_time LIKE curdate() but it can never works because log_time contains even the time